# Recover CM system with bad Google Apps update

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb

I recently updated [Google Apps](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) on my device. Now, when I start my phone, I get repeatedly inundated with "Unfortunately, {{app}} has stopped." with Keep, Gmail, Wallet, etc. filling in the blanks. The dialogs stack up, and whenever I manage to dismiss all of them, they pop up again about a half-second later, making it impossible to do anything. I've enabled ADB on the phone, but it isn't listed when I run `adb devices`.

I think I could probably wipe the phone/factory reset, but I have data I'd like to pull off first. Is there anything else I could try?

CM 12.1

Comment: Which device? If CM 12.1 is the custom ROM you installed, you might be having a custom recovery. Why not take a backup from there and transfer it to PC. If the CM 12.1 is the official ROM of the device, then you can take backup from official recovery but I'm not sure whether you can extract it or not since restoring it completely would reproduce the issue again in future.

Comment: Is the old gapps.zip still on the sdcard?

Comment: What OS are you running `adb` on?